# Adding ConditionStep in Sagemaker Pipeline, fails with Access deined permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm in a weird situation. I have a Sagemaker pipeline, which has 4 SparkJarProcessor jobs.
For each of them, I'm creating the arguments -

```
args = spark_processor.run(
    submit_app = "<project>.jar",
    submit_class = "Main",
    arguments = [<arguments>],
    logs = False,
    configuration = configuration,
    submit_jars = ["<additional_jars>.jar"],
    kms_key = "<kms_key>"
    )
```

and creating pipeline step -

```
step_processing = ProcessingStep(name="ProcessingStep",step_args=args)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    name=pipeline_name,
    parameters=[],
    steps=[step_processing]
)
```

So Im trying to add the condition_step for each of the step, in a such a way that each step would have a input parameter set to true, then the step would run else skip.

```
step_cond = ConditionStep(
    name="Execution",
    conditions=[cond_ssdc],
    if_steps=[step_processing],
    else_steps=[]
)
```

The pipeline runs the prefect, if there's no condition_step.
If I add minimal setup condition_step, the pipeline fails with below error -

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/spark/processing.py in _extend_processing_args(self, inputs, outputs, **kwargs)
    322             configuration = kwargs.get("configuration")
    323             self._validate_configuration(configuration)
--> 324             extended_inputs.append(self._stage_configuration(configuration))
    325 
    326         return (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/spark/processing.py in _stage_configuration(self, configuration)
    454             body=serialized_configuration,
    455             desired_s3_uri=s3_uri,
--> 456             sagemaker_session=self.sagemaker_session,
    457         )
    458 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/s3.py in upload_string_as_file_body(body, desired_s3_uri, kms_key, sagemaker_session)
     87 
     88         sagemaker_session.upload_string_as_file_body(
---> 89             body=body, bucket=bucket, key=key, kms_key=kms_key
     90         )
     91 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in upload_string_as_file_body(self, body, bucket, key, kms_key)
    418             s3_object.put(Body=body, SSEKMSKeyId=kms_key, ServerSideEncryption="aws:kms")
    419         else:
--> 420             s3_object.put(Body=body)
    421 
    422         s3_uri = "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, key)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py in do_action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    578             # instance via ``self``.
    579             def do_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 580                 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
    581 
    582                 if hasattr(self, 'load'):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py in __call__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
     86         )
     87 
---> 88         response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
     89 
     90         logger.debug('Response: %r', response)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    962             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    963             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 964             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    965         else:
    966             return parsed_response
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I see that somewhere it is accessing s3. Im not sure why? is it expected? Do we need to add the **spark_event_logs_s3_uri** also if we add condition_step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it ( in a harder way ), ConditionStep uses s3 for some internal operations ( couldn't find it what and where ), the Sagemaker role used for the pipeline had no access to the bucket. So I added the right permission and was able to execute it.